# Racket can't plot a surface

Tags: plot, racket

I want to plot this surface:

z = (3x - 8 + 11y) / (6y -11)

Here is the code

```
(plot3d (surface 
   (lambda (x y) (/ (+ (* 3 x) -8 (* 11 y)) (- (* 6 y) 11)) 0 1 0 1)) 
   #:x-min 0 #:x-max 1 #:y-min 0 #:y-max 1)
```

However, Racket produces a strange (and wrong graph). I try this function on academo.org and it plots just fine.

https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter/?expression=(3x-8%2B11y)%2F(6y-11)&xRange=0%2C1&yRange=0%2C1&resolution=25

Does anybody knows why? Because I need to plot multiple surfaces in a same graph and I cannot do that on academo. I have only Racket as graphing tool on my laptop.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Use `surface3d` (not `surface`). Easy oversight.

Comment: Thank you. Seems that `surface` has another function.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, `surface` does not work but `surface3d` works.

```
(plot3d (surface3d  
   (lambda (x y) (/ (+ (* 3 x) -8 (* 11 y)) (- (* 6 y) 11))) 0 1 0 1))
```

Though I still do not know why.